# spring boot startup fails when using war built on jenkins

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins, centos, redhat

We have a spring-boot application, built as a .war assembly (Maven build), which is deployed on the server with simple java -jar command.

As a part of CI/CD, the same code is being built on Jenkins. The Jenkins server is CentOS and the target deployment server is RedHat. The .war file built on Jenkins fails with Spring Beans Cyclic Dependency resolution error, while the same code when built on local(Mac OS) or on RedHat server works fine.

I tried to look through the war file, for each and every dependency, and everything looks same except for jsp-api-2.1 jar. The jsp-api-2.1.jar included in .war built on Jenkins has Created-By: 1.5.0_06-b04 in MANIFEST.MF, while the jsp-api-2.1.jar included in .war built on local (MacOs) or on Redhat has Created-By: 1.5.0_04-b05 in MANIFEST.MF. Other than this all other dependencies are the same.

The war files' sizes differ slightly, however, I could not find any difference other than what mentioned above.

The error which we are getting on Jenkins built jar is below,

```
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

|  Class A
↑     ↓
|  Class B
└─────┘
```

Does Maven generate any OS specific files, or are the dependencies downloaded from repository OS specific?

I can't really think of anything as both the .war files look similar. Any information on this will be helpful.

Comment: Enable debug logging to get the actual stacktrace instead of the analyzed failure.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'beanA': Bean with name 'beanA' has been injected into other beans [beanB] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:585)

Comment: We don't see this error on the other war

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace to your question and not as a comment that is totally unreadable.

Comment: Apparently you aren't using the same build procedure to create the war on jenkins as you are doing locally. Use the same build system (maven) to build and create the war.

Comment: Are java versions same on all the systems?

Comment: Hi Jignesh, Yes, the java version is same. @M.Deinum I will look into the build procedure again.

Comment: The fact that dependencies differ is an indication. Make sure you are using the same Java, Maven version and that, when using profiles, things don't differ too much!.

Comment: I removed the dependency which was changing (jsp-api). Now the wars differ by 3 bytes, and that difference is from the MANIFEST file, Built-By: and Implementation-Version sections. I am investigating further & trying to implement profiles